# JavaScript/jQuery: Split a Text up to Occurence of a Symbol Using Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

I have a text content as follows:

```
var text = "asd^dfdf^dsfgdsfg^zdfsd^sdfsdf^dfsdf^dsfsdf^dfsdf^dfsf^sdfsdf^..."
```

I want to split the text up-to **multiple of 5th occurrence of** `^` and pass to a function with the `^` symbol.

If there are 31 `^` in the element then: 5th, 10th, 15th, 20th, 25th, 30th and then remaining should be passed to the function (i.e. 31st with `^`).

I prefer a `for` loop like:

```
var spl = text.split(); //up-to 5th multiple

for(i=0; i<spl.length; i++){
 passfun(upto 5th^ with cap symbol)
}
```

Example:

```
var text = "asd^dfdf^dsfgdsfg^zdfsd^sdfsdf^dfsdf^dsfsdf^dfsdf^dfsf^sdfsdf^sssad^gsds..."

passfun("asd^dfdf^dsfgdsfg^zdfsd^sdfsdf^"); //1st time
passfun("dfsdf^dsfsdf^dfsdf^dfsf^sdfsdf^");//2nd time
passfun("sssad^gsds");//last
```

Comment: I would split on every '^' then in the for loop add 5 strings to one line.

Comment: @ Poul Bak can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
var text = "asd^dfdf^dsfgdsfg^zdfsd^sdfsdf^dfsdf^dsfsdf^dfsdf^dfsf^sdfsdf^...";
var spl = text.split('^');
Array.prototype.chunk = function ( n ) {
    if ( !this.length ) {
        return [];
    }
    return [ this.slice( 0, n ) ].concat( this.slice(n).chunk(n) );
};
console.log(spl.chunk(5)[0].join('^')+'^');
```

more info 
[Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)

demo here:
https://jsfiddle.net/bo4eacv5/1/

Comment: you remove the  +'^' at the last

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
var text = "asd^dfdf^dsfgdsfg^zdfsd^sdfsdf^dfsdf^dsfsdf^dfsdf^dfsf^sdfsdf",
    temp = text.split('^');
for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i += 5) {
  passfun(temp.slice(i, 5 + i).join('^') + ( i + 5 < temp.length ? '^' : ''));
}
```

Comment: check it https://jsfiddle.net/bo4eacv5/3/. Upto ^ symbol in your code ^ symbol missing

Answer (score 0):

Hello friend it perfect little bit may be length correction need if you  have any problem then otherwise no need

```
var text = "asd^dfdf^dsfgdsfg^zdfsd^sdfsdf^dfsdf^dsfsdf^dfsdf^dfsf^sdfsdf^split^text^upto^5th^and^..";
                //I want to split the text upto multiple of 5th occurrance of ^ and
                //var abc =  text.split("^").length - 1;
                var counter = 0, index = 0;
                var temp = 0, indexArr = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
                    index++;
                    if (text.charAt(i) == '^') {
                        counter++;
                    }
                    if (counter == 5) {
                        counter = 0;
                        myString(index);
                    }
                }
                function myString(tempindex) {
                    var tempString = '';
                    indexArr[temp] = tempindex;
                    if (temp == 0) {
                        tempString = text.substr(0, tempindex);
                        passfun(tempString);
                        temp++;
                    } else {
                        tempString = text.substr(indexArr[temp - 1], indexArr[temp - 1]);
                        passfun(tempString);
                        temp++;
                    }
                    return;
                }
```